# Where should function prototypes be declared?

Tags: c++, readability, function-prototypes

Where exactly should the prototypes be declared? For example right after the include statments, or right before the main method? I know they both compile but is one considered more standard or more redable?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

const unsigned int PI = 3.14;

using namespace std;

int myFunc(int x, int y);
long factorial(int n);

int main()
{
  //...
  return 0;
}
```

or

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int myFunc(int x, int y);
long factorial(int n);

using namespace std;



int main()
{
  //...
  return 0;
}
```

or shoudl they not be used at all and main should be declared last?

No one has really addressed if one way is more readable or prefered.

Comment: In your example, it doesn't make a difference. Somewhere before a function is actually called.

Comment: Your two programs don't have any difference. You shouldn't be using `using namespace std` anyway.

Comment: i would suggest to put them in a header, and have main solo in that translation unit.

Answer (score 1):

It would only matter if you actually used a type from the `std` in your function prototypes.  In your example you don't, so it doesn't matter in your case.

This would not compile:

```
#include <string>

void foo(string const & s);

using namespace std;
```

But this would:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void foo(string const & s);
```

But [you shouldn't use `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/501250) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A function prototype must be declared before the function usage. It may be declared even in a block scope.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you have shown it doesn't matter.

The rule is:

> A function has to be declared ***before*** you use it (in this case: call it).

**Note:** If the function is defined before its usage then you don't need explicit function declaration. The function definition serves the purpose.